# How to resolve the slf4j binding error in gradle?

Tags: java, debugging, gradle, dependencies, spotbugs

I am seeing this error during my gradle build with spotbugs enabled.

```
0:12.450 [DEBUG] [system.err] SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
21:50:12.450 [DEBUG] [system.err] SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/me/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/my-plugin/0.6.1/ced3c13362d615ad7b387350d72eac6b16c1a384/myplugin.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
21:50:12.450 [DEBUG] [system.err] SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/me/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-5.4-all/es474nxjx6mx8lyhiqcf2v68i/gradle-5.4/lib/gradle-logging-5.4.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
21:50:12.450 [DEBUG] [system.err] SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
21:50:12.465 [DEBUG] [system.err] SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.gradle.internal.logging.slf4j.OutputEventListenerBackedLoggerContext]
21:50:12.526 [DEBUG] [system.err] org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: java.io.InvalidClassException: org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 5823396045992867804, local class serialVersionUID = -7173837137173599142
21:50:12.526 [DEBUG] [system.err]       at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:57)
21:50:12.526 [DEBUG] [system.err]       at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:40)
21:50:12.526 [DEBUG] [system.err]       at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:109)
21:50:12.526 [DEBUG] [system.err]       at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:64)
21:50:12.526 [DEBUG] [system.err]       at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:62)
21:50:12.526 [DEBUG] [system.err]       at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:67)
21:50:12.526 [DEBUG] [system.err] Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 5823396045992867804, local class serialVersionUID = -7173837137173599142
21:50:12.526 [DEBUG] [system.err]       at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:689)
21:50:12.526 [DEBUG] [system.err]       at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1903)
21:50:12.526 [DEBUG] [system.err]       at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1772)
21:50:12.526 [DEBUG] [system.err]       at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2060)
21:50:12.526 [DEBUG] [system.err]       at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1594)
21:50:12.526 [DEBUG] [system.err]       at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:430)
21:50:12.526 [DEBUG] [system.err]       at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:107)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Post `build.gradle` file contents here.

Comment: What's `my-plugin/0.6.1`?

Comment: Are you asking how to solve the warning about multiple SLF4J bindings on your classpath, or why your builds fails with an InvalidClassException on internal Gradle classes? The latter might happen if you use an old version of Spotbugs with a new version of Gradle.